# Access global variable from UDF (User Defined Function) in python in spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, global-variables, user-defined-functions

I am trying to alter a global variable from inside a `pyspark.sql.functions.udf` function in python. But, the change in not getting reflected in the global variable.

The reproducible example along with outputs is:

```
counter = 0

schema2 = StructType([\
    StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("name", StringType(), True)   
])

data2 = [(1, "A"), (2, "B")]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data = data2, schema = schema2)

def myFunc(column):
    global counter
    counter = counter + 1
    return column + 5
  
myFuncUDF = udf(myFunc, IntegerType())

display(df.withColumn('id1', myFuncUDF(df.id)))
```

Output:

| id | name | id1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 6 |
| 2 | B | 7 |

When I print the counter variable, it remains 0.

**Can anyone help me to know how to access a global variable inside a UDF and alter the global variable on each call to the UDF?** or whether it is not possible?

Comment: Will that help? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.Accumulator.html

Comment: @mazaneicha Are accumulator variables thread-safe? If we have a custom accumulator variable, that is a set.

Each row then adds its ID to the accumulator if it already does not exist and updates its boolean variable (as another col) which marks whether it adds to the accumulator set. If id already exists, then, the row does not add its id.

In this case, can we expect the integrity of the final boolean column output?

Comment: I was just saying that googling things before asking questions is a best practice. For the accumulators, see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#shared-variables. There you can find out that _"...Tasks running on a cluster can then add to it using the add method. However, they **cannot read its value**. Only the driver program can read the accumulator’s value, using its value method..."_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create a custom set accumulator to store the id's.

```
class SetAccumulator(AccumulatorParam):
    def zero(self, init_value: set()):
        return init_value
    
    def addInPlace(self, v1: set, v2: set):
        return v1.union(v2)
```

To initialise the set set accumulator, and add to the accumulator from each thread where our spark job is running while transforming the dataframe. Reference -

```
#accumulator initialization
acc = spark.sparkContext.accumulator(set(), SetAccumulator())

schema2 = StructType([\
    StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("name", StringType(), True)   
])

data2 = [(1, "A"), (2, "B")]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data = data2, schema = schema2)

#access accumulator as a global variable inside the udf 
def myFunc(column):
    global acc
    int_set = set()
    int_set.add(column)
    acc += int_set
    return column + 5
  
myFuncUDF = udf(myFunc, IntegerType())
```